# Запятая между "то" и "что"

Tags: запятые

"Я буду говорить то что захочу". Нужно ли ставить здесь запятую?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая ставится: ***Я буду говорить то,  что захочу*.**

Это обычное сложноподчиненное предложение с местоименно-определительным придаточным.

Запятая не ставится в цельных выражениях: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146#pp146

2. Выражения с глаголом **хотеть,** образующие цельные по смыслу выражения, запятой не разделяются: пиши как хочешь (‘пиши по-всякому’); над ним, командует кто хочет; его не гоняет только кто не хочет; приходи когда хочешь; бери сколько хочешь; гуляй с кем хочешь; **делай что хочешь**; распоряжайтесь как хотите; напишет какую хочешь статью; выпьет какое хочешь вино; женись на ком хочешь.

Примечание (дополнительная информация)

Запятая будет ставится и в таком предложении: *Я буду говорить,  **что захочу.*** Здесь глагол совершенного вида "захотеть".

Но запятая может не ставиться в следующем предложении: Я буду говорить  **что хочУ**, никто мне не запретит.  Здесь  нет  паузы.

Цельный оборот в этом случае близок по значению к одному слову или словосочетанию: *Я буду говорить **любые вещи**.*

В то же время варианты возможны и здесь при другой расстановке ударения:

*Я буду **говорИть**, **что хочУ**.* Поэтому всегда нужно учитывать контекст.